# How to use interactive with a Box containing widgets?

Tags: ipywidgets

Using `interactive` is fairly simple with multiple widgets, for example:

```
interactive(foo, w1=widget1, w2=widget2, ...)
```

However I would like to layout these widgets in a specific manner, using combinations of VBox and HBox. Question is, how can I use interative with a box?

I have tried a couple of ways such as calling interactive with the widgets of the Box then displaying the box itself but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the widgets [documentation](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html):

> In addition to `interact`, IPython provides another function, `interactive`, that is useful when you want to reuse the widgets that are produced or access the data that is bound to the UI controls.
>   [...]
>   Unlike `interact`, `interactive` returns a `Widget` instance rather than immediately displaying the widget. The widget is a `Box`, which is a container for other widgets.

So here you already have `w` as a Box container for which you can change the layout properties.

```
w = interactive(foo, w1=widget1, w2=widget2)
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, although my original issue was that I wanted to interact with, for example, a box like : 

`VBox((HBox(w1, w2), HBox(w3, w4)))`

Comment: The widget actually initializes a `VBox` and it "Displays multiple widgets vertically using the flexible box model."

Comment: How do you display the output outside of the `interactive` box?

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered same issue, and figured out that we need to use `interactive_output`.

```
out = interactive_output(foo, {"w1":w1, "w2":w2, "w3":w3, "w4":w4})
vbox1 = VBox([w1, w2])
vbox2 = VBoX([w3, w4])
ui = HBox([vbox1, vbox2])

accordian = Accordian(children=[ui])
accordian.set_title(0, 'Title')

display(accordian, out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [interactive_output](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html#interactive_output)

Something like:

```
t1 = Text(value='Hello 1', description='row 1')
t2 = Text(value='Hello 2', description='')
t3 = Text(value='Hello 3', description='')
t4 = Text(value='Hello 4', description='row 2')
t5 = Text(value='Hello 5', description='')
t6 = Text(value='Hello 6', description='')
t7 = Text(value='Hello 7', description='row 3')
t8 = Text(value='Hello 8', description='')
t9 = Text(value='Hello 9', description='')

def foo(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9):
    print(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9)

out = interactive_output(foo, {"p1":t1, "p2":t2, "p3":t3, "p4":t4, "p5":t5, "p6":t6, "p7":t7, "p8":t8, "p9":t9})
hbox1 = HBox([t1, t2, t3])
hbox2 = HBox([t4, t5, t6])
hbox3 = HBox([t7, t8, t9])
ui = VBox([hbox1, hbox2, hbox3])

display(ui, out)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Note: This is my first time answering in stack overflow so apologies if I haven't figured out yet how to post blocks of code here, but I'll do my best to format them.)

Just like what others have said, use interactive_output for this. From the documentation at https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html ,
there is a sample code illustrating this:

```
a = widgets.IntSlider()
b = widgets.IntSlider()
c = widgets.IntSlider()
ui = widgets.HBox([a, b, c])
def f(a, b, c):
    print((a, b, c))

out = widgets.interactive_output(f, {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c})

display(ui, out)
```

I actually implemented this in my own code where I used HBox and VBox to form a 2x2 grid of widgets. I'm plotting the product of an exponential function and a general sine wave with the amplitude, exponential decay, frequency, and phase being varied via sliders. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as wgs
from ipywidgets import HBox, VBox
%matplotlib inline

def f(A, decay, wd, phase):
    t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 501)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,4), dpi=100)
    x = A*np.exp(-decay*t)*np.sin(wd*t + phase)
    ax.plot(t, x, 'b.', linewidth = 3)
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_title(r'$ %(amp)s e^{ -%(sig)s t} sin( %(wd)s t + %(phi)s ) $' %{'amp':A, 'sig':decay, 'wd':wd, 'phi':phase,} )
    ax.set_xlabel('t')
    ax.set_ylabel('x(t)')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (seconds)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Displacement (meters)')
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(min(t),max(t), 21))
    ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(-A, A,11))  
    return A, decay, wd, phase
A  = wgs.IntSlider(value = 1, min = 1, max = 10, step = 1, description = r'$ A : $', disabled=False)
decay = wgs.FloatSlider(value = 0, min = 0, max = 10, step = 0.5, description = r'$ \sigma : $', disabled=False)
wd    = wgs.IntSlider(value = 1, min = 1, max = 20, step = 1, description = r'$ \omega_d : $', disabled=False)
phase = wgs.FloatSlider(value = 0, min = -1.5, max = 1.5, step = 0.1, description = r'$ \phi : $', disabled=False)
row1 = HBox( [A, decay] )
row2 = HBox( [wd, phase] )
ui = VBox( [row1, row2] )
out = wgs.interactive_output(f, {'A':A, 'decay':decay, 'wd':wd, 'phase':phase} )
display(ui, out)
```